# why doesn't this breakpoint get hit within this Parallel.ForEach()?

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, async-await, parallel.foreach

I have the method below which contains a Parallel.ForEach().  The line of code with the "reference1" comment to the right finds "My_Group_X" as expected (when the line of code is uncommented) and subsequently hits the line of code with the inline comment of "reference2."  However, if I do a full FindAll() without the additional filtering line marked with "reference1" then the subsequent line marked with "reference2" does not get hit.  This behavior seems contrary to logic since an open FindAll() which returns all records should certainly include the record which is found when a specific filter is applied.  Any idea what the issue might be here or how to solve?  I get these same test results every time:

```
private async Task GetADGroupADUserMapFromAD(string domainName)
{
        //get domain id
        var domainId = domainLookup.Where(x => x.Name == domainName).First().Id;
        using (var searchContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName))
        {
            var ps = new PrincipalSearcher(new GroupPrincipal(searchContext));
            Parallel.ForEach(
                    ps.FindAll()
                    //.Where(x => x.Name.ToUpper() == "MY_GROUP_X") //reference1
                    .Select(x => x.DistinguishedName),
                    new ParallelOptions() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount },
                    () => new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domainName),
                    (distinguishedName, loopState, threadLocalContext) =>
                    {
                        var threadLocalGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(
                            threadLocalContext, IdentityType.DistinguishedName, distinguishedName);

                        if (threadLocalGroup.Name.ToUpper() == "MY_GROUP_X") 
                        {
                            var x = 0; //reference2 
                        }

                        GetADGroupADUsersRecursive(domainId, threadLocalGroup);

                        return threadLocalContext;
                    },
                    threadLocalContext => threadLocalContext?.Dispose()
                );
        }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you convert your action to a function and put a break point there and see if it hits. If not then it may possible that the source `ps.FindAll().......` is not returning an collection.

Comment: does this work outside of a parrallel for each

Comment: Besides the `async` modifier in the method, does this have anything to do with `async-await`? What other warnings are being ignored?

Comment: looks like the breakpoint is getting hit now when I update the code to ps.FindAll().AsEnumerable().  any idea why that is?